# Creating a button that can store a number

Tags: gui-construction, button

I would like to create a button which has the action of storing a numerical input. Is this possible?

For example, a button which I click, then enter "5", produces the result the the number 5 gets stored somewhere based on which button I clicked.

Comment: This is not a well posed question -- "stored somewhere" is too vague and so is "enter '5'". Please edit the question to give more details. Do not post the additional details in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for a simple approach:

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[x], Range[10]], Dynamic[x]}
```

or if you want to compute a simple function of your number:

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[x], Range[10]], Dynamic[x], Dynamic[N[Cos[x]]]}
```

If you want it to look nice:

```
Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[x], Range[10]], 
       Dynamic[x], 
       Dynamic[N[Cos[x]]]}, Center]
```